# Reading strings from lines in java - StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range

Tags: java, string

I wanted to get a words (the name of artist between "|" and ":") from my text file and on the output i get what i want, but also an:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3..."

It's my code:

```
public class MyMainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        try {
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter nr : ");
            String nr = console.nextLine();                
            File originalFile = new File("albums.txt");
            BufferedReader br;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(originalFile));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains(nr)) {
                    String artysta = line.substring(line.indexOf("|") +1, line.indexOf(":"));
                    System.out.println("artysta: " + artysta);
                }  
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyMainClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyMainClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 
}
```

I have correct output result, and the name of (artysta) but also this:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1954) at MyMainClass.MyMainClass.main(MyMainClass.java:38) Java Result: 1"
```

Here is a sample of the String in my file. Each number 1| and so on starts a new line.

```
1|Deerhunter:Microcastle||49,99|||95 
2|John Lennon:Imagine||59,99|||50 
3|The Cure:Faith||40,00|||80
```

Any idea how to remove this error?

Comment: post an example of the text you are reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot be sure that when you're using `+1` in your code, this is in the String length range, so you first need to check that:

```
if ((line.indexOf("|") +1) < line.length() ){
.
.
}
```

Comment: This is how it looks on my text file:
2|John Lennon:Imagine

Comment: Finally I added my full code above.
And my text file:
1|Deerhunter:Microcastle||49,99|||95
2|John Lennon:Imagine||59,99|||50
3|The Cure:Faith||40,00|||80   Of course the numbers starts in a new line

Comment: I just turn on my computer today and it actually works :) Anyway thanks for your solution. Now I'll try to set this result on jTextField on my main project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the substring to retrieve is located right before the last `:` as you showed in the code. Try

```
if (line.contains(nr)) {
  String aStr = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(nr)-1, line.lastIndexOf(":"));
}
```

UPDATE: **2|John Lennon:the rest of information**

Using above sample string from your comment. Try

```
String aStr = line.substring(line.indexOf("|"), line.indexOf(":"));
```

Comment: Yes but first it check if the line contains a number(nr) that i wrtie on output. In my file it looks like this:
2|John Lennon:the rest of information
So when i wrrite 2, then I'll get John Lennon and this error.

Comment: could you post the complete string on the question?